# How to get data for an Instagram Business account from Instagram Business API without login?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I have been approved for Instagram Business API and only use to call data from Insights, which is working fine for logged in users.

I am trying to get basic data from API for IG accounts accounts that a user doesn't own, such as followers, following, posts, post likes, post comments, post caption, post date.

Tried what it says here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/business-discovery/:

```
GET graph.facebook.com/v3.2/{id}?fields=business_discovery.username(bluebottle){followers_count,media_count,media{comments_count,like_count}}
```

And this is the error we got:

```
{
  "error": 
    "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (business_discovery) on node type (Business)".
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "FYrJiGR310k"
  }
}
```

I can't find anywhere in the documentation on how to do this, but before anyone says it's not possible, there are two websites that I know already do this right now: https://www.owlstat.com and https://web.stagram.com

I thought maybe they could be also doing this https://www.instagram.com/web/search/topsearch/?context=user&count=0&query=bluebottle but that's not a long term solution.

Hope someone can help! Thanks.

Comment: "it didn't work" is quite broad, please add more details.

Comment: @luschn Just added more details with the error I got in Facebook. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The {id} in your example needs to be the Instagram Business ID of the page that was granted Instagram Business API permissions. To find it, open the Facebook Graph Explorer and run this with a User Access Token:

```
GET graph.facebook.com/v3.2/accounts?fields=instagram_business_account{id,username}
```

You'll see your Instagram Business ID. Then, using a Page Access Token, do:

```
GET graph.facebook.com/v3.2/{id}?fields=business_discovery.username(bluebottle){followers_count,media_count,media{comments_count,like_count}}
```

replacing {id} with your Instagram Business ID.

Comment: Hi there. We did add the ID when making the call, but still get the same error when using what you sent. "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (business_discovery) on node type (Business)". We're trying to get basic data from public IG Business Accounts.

Comment: What ID are you using?

Comment: Yeah, we had the same issue. Our users had to have Instagram Business accounts linked to a Facebook Page to view insights